dynamic js file generation in serenity.is framwork
I ran a project
and I've wanted to write a lookup to return Role info, but after running it, I saw that all the information of the Roles are in a file named "https://localhost:1429/DynJS.axd/Lookup.Administration.Role.js" which is displayed before the login
Why has serenity use DynJS.axd?
is there special reason? and finally how to disable this files in my project?

there's an attribute to define certain objects as "lookup scripts": https://serenity.is/Docs/api/dotnet/Serenity.Net.Core/Serenity.ComponentModel/LookupScriptAttribute.md  Presumably this is to improve speed (and reduce amount of DB calls?), but security-wise dynamic scripts returned from an endpoint are a bit sketchy, imo.

presumably JSONP is returned.... see this wikipedia article which lists security concerns: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP  I believe Serenity states that only ID and Name are in any of those script objects, but not sure the benefits outweigh the risks especially since you'll need to relax any csp settings.

also see these docs: https://serenity.is/Docs/framework/dynamic-scripts/lookups
